# Maximum of a subset of array (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, optimization

Suppose in MATLAB I have a real matrix `A` which is `n x m` and a binary matrix `B` of the same size. The latter matrix defines the optimization set (all indices for which the element of `B` equals one): over this set I would like to find the maximal element of A. How can I do this?

The first idea I had is that I consider `C = A.*B` and look for the maximal element of `C`. This works fine for all matrices `A` which have at least one positive element, however it does not work for matrices with all negative elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
C = A(B==1);
```

to give you an array of just the values of A corresponding to a value of 1 in B. And

```
max( C )
```

will give you the maximum value of A where B is 1

With this method you don't run into a problem when all values of A are negative as the zeros don't appear in C.

Obviously you can condense this to

```
desiredValue = max(A(B(:)==1));
```

I am using the colon operator to make sure that the result of `A(B(:)==1)` is a column vector - if B is all ones I am not sure if Matlab would return a vector or a `nxm` matrix (and I can't confirm right now).

**update** to get the index of the value, you can do:

```
f = find(B==1);
[m mi] = max(A(f));
maxIndex = f(mi);
```

And to get that back to the 2D elements:

```
[i j] = ind2sub(size(A), maxIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in the element, not in the value per se. Would it be possible to update your solution to that?